# Bootstrap sidebar not collapsing as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This question follows from one I asked earlier but is a separate problem: [Left sidebar with toggle in Bootstrap 3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186743/left-sidebar-with-toggle-in-bootstrap-3-not-working/)

jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/y9khea25/1/

I have implemented the answer (on a local copy) which sorts out the position of the hamburger menu to open/close the left sidebar.

However, when I resize my browser window to the breakpoint in the media query `(max-width:767px)` , I get the following:

[image]

The media query is being used because the left sidebar is supposed to collapse at the breakpoint:

```
    @media (max-width:767px) {
        main {
            padding-left: 70px;
            transition: all .4s ease 0s;
        }
        #sidebar {
            left: 70px;
        }
        main.active {
            padding-left: 150px;
        }
        main.active #sidebar {
            left: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            transition: all .4s ease 0s;
        }
    }
```

I don't know if the issue is further being caused by the fact I'm using the following Bootstrap classes inside `<main>`, `.col-sm-3 .col-md-2` for the left sidebar and `.col-xs-12 .col-sm-9 .col-md-10` for the content. However this is required because I want those column proportions for the sidebar and content. I don't understand if they are being used though because  `#sidebar` has a fixed width of 150px in the CSS.

Please can someone help as I'm stuck with this?

The effect shown on the fiddle is correct, except at the breakpoint I want the left sidebar in a "collapsed" position, with the ability to re-open it using the hamburger menu (`#menu-toggle`).

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the issue, but the sidebar, at 767px seems to be at the right place, however the hamburger icon is not...

Comment: @Matt - thanks. Are you running it from jsfiddle or locally? I needed to run it locally to get this because the jsfiddle site didn't change it at the breakpoint - possibly due to the way it's contained within it's own "panel" on their website.

Comment: Updated the hamburger menu position: https://jsfiddle.net/y9khea25/12/